# vscode python debugger does not react to breakpoints or stoponentry

Tags: python, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug the simplest python code. The debugger does not hit any breakpoints and just simply runs through the code.

My python path is set correctly. StopOnEntry does nothing with either true or false. I ve seen many questions similar to this, howevere none of the provided a solution. I am not leaning towards the idea that this is a bug, but it may be so.

```
print("1")
print("0")
```

launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "E:/Program Files/PythonFiles/new.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

No error messages in the terminal, just expected output

Comment: Did you specify the file `"program": "E:/Program Files/PythonFiles/new.py",` on purpose? Because the configuration name says `...Current File"`.

Comment: yes, i was desperately trying to figure out what stops the debugger from launching and was playing around with pythonPath and "program". neither seems to be the issue since the result is the same with specified in the code path or just ${file}